# Put input date in thymeleaf table

Tags: html, date, thymeleaf

I want to put an input with a date selection instead of this:
`<td th:text="${#dates.format(client[3], 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm')}"></td>` and with a value client[3]

client[3] its -> date & time

I want the date to be changeable. What do I need to do?

```
 <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>Last Name</td>
          <td>Email</td>
          <td>End Date</td>
          <th>Change datetime</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="someclass" th:each="client : ${ClientsInSystem}">
          <td th:text="${client[1]}"></td>
          <td th:text="${client[2]}"></td>
          <td th:text="${client[0]}"></td>
          <td th:text="${#dates.format(client[3], 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm')}"></td>
<!--          <input type="date" id="start" th:value="${#dates.format(client[3], 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm')}">-->
          <td>
            <button th:href="${'bla'}">Extend trial</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found what i need :)

```
 <tr class="someClass" th:each="client : ${ClientsInSystem}">
              <td th:text="${client[1]}"></td>
              <td th:text="${client[2]}"></td>
              <td th:text="${client[0]}"></td>
              <td> <input type="date" id="dateForUpdate" th:value="${#dates.format(client[3], 'yyyy-MM-dd')}"> </td>
              <td> <button class="btn" th:onclick="updateDateForTrialUser()">Extend trial</button> </td>
              </td>
            </tr>
```